# How do I show Variable Bindings in SICSTUS' "SPIDER" IDE?

Tags: eclipse, ide, sicstus-prolog

I'm using the "SPIDER" IDE for SICSTUS Prolog development, as instructed by the SICSTUS Manual and the documentation on the SPIDER IDE itself. When debugging, under the 'SICSTUS Debugging' perspective, the variables do not show on the Variables window, as can be seen in the top right in the image [shown here](http://sicstus.sics.se/spider/) (it's the first thing in the Spider page)

I set up everything according to [this guide](http://sicstus.sics.se/spider/prerequisites.html) and this is, as far as I can tell, the only thing not working. Are there any additional steps to get the variable bindings while debugging?

Thanks in advance,

edit: I've recently reinstalled everything in the same system after formatting a drive, and it now works perfectly. I have no idea what, but I assume I did something wrong the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable bindings should work by default. However, some variables may be omitted depending on compiler optimizations and other factors. Try it with the example program shown in the SPIDER image.